# Purpose of the JAVA_HOME, M2, and M2_HOME variables

Tags: java, maven, path

What do I need the `JAVA_HOME`, `M2`, and `M2_HOME` environment variables for if the paths that should go there are already appended to my PATH variable?

Comment: i dont understand. could you try and elaborate please?

Comment: They are used for other applications to find your java (or M2) installation for comparing versions for compatibility, among other things.

Comment: How would you find *specifically* JAVA_HOME, M2 and M2_HOME inside the PATH variable? Right, other programs needing this specific information would face exactly the same problem.

Comment: They're not appended to the system path. They're used by apps and *may* be used as *part* of an addition to the system path.

Comment: I added path to jdk/bin and to maven/bin to PATH variable. Now i can run maven commands from command line and use java.  What for JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME are used? Which programms will use them?

Answer (score 8):

`JAVA_HOME` should refer to directory where Java that you want to use is installed. This variable is often used by various scripts, so it is recommended to define it. `JAVA_HOME` itself should not be added to `PATH`. You should add `JAVA_HOME/bin` to be able to run commands from this directory without specifying the concrete path.

`M2_HOME` is a home of Maven. It is used by script `mvn` (or `mvn.bat` on Windows).

Comment: Strange why mvn README does not say anything about setting this variable during installation :(

Comment: @ACV, `JAVA_HOME` is an environment variable, invented and relevant for JRE. Maven is a build tool written in java. Typically we are not expecting that each software product that uses certain technology or programming language will explain essentials of this technology in its README file. It is like expecting that manual of your TV will contain introduction to the Ohm's law.

Comment: Funny but as far as  I remember, "Ohm's law" was present in older releases of maven: "4) Make sure JAVA_HOME is set to the location of your JDK" http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip So why was it removed?

Answer (score 7):

The home paths (`JAVA_HOME`, `M2_HOME`) are not mandatory but good to have. One of the advantages is:

It helps you make changes at one place rather than search you way in the `PATH` variable when you install next version of Java or Maven. For example `JAVA_HOME` environment variable below is a one place I need to change when I upgrade it to Java Development Kit 1.8.

[image: Windows environment variable window]

Answer (score 5):

I think you do not understand a concept of environment variable. For start, read here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

`PATH` is one environment variable that is well known in many operating systems (or shells).  And it's meaning is that if you type a program name without full path, operating system (or shell) will try to search all directories specified in `PATH` variable.

Other programs have different dependencies on the environment. Some of them specify which environment variables they need in order to run properly.

`JAVA_HOME` is used by many Java-based applications to define the place of Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installation.

`M2_HOME` is used by Maven, and again it tells the program where to find Maven installation.

`PATH` is not suitable for that purpose, because it may contain many directories not related to Java or Maven.

Answer (score 1):

The PATH variable is used to find applications (executables, and scripts) and DLLs on Windows.  If you type "mvn", then the PATH is used to locate an executable or script of that name.   Just because the script is found in a location, however, doesn't mean that the application is installed in that directory.  The easiest example to describe is one that exists on UNIX.  You might have a symbolic link from /usr/local/bin/mvn to the location where maven is actually installed.  Other examples/reasons could be given.

The environment variables are used by the application to know where to look for other resources the application might need.

For example, JAVA_HOME points to the directory where your JDK can be found.  When JAVA runs, that application knows that other resources can be found relative to the JAVA_HOME directory.

This allows the application for example C:\Windows\System32\java to exist in one directory but the JDK installation to be located somewhere else.

The same applies for the M2_HOME directory which points to the top directory where MAVEN is "installed" (or unzipped).

The M2 directory specifies to the maven application (mvn) where to find the maven repositories that are needed.  The default (on UNIX) is $HOME/.m2, but you might not want your repository there so you can specify another location using the M2 environment variable and maven will use that location instead of the default.